# passing comparator to collections.sort() in Java?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, treeset

I have the following code where I have a Treeset, to which if I pass my comparator it works fine.
however, if I construct my Treeset and then call collections.sort, I get compile error.
my code is here

```
import java.util.*;

public class ComparatorExample {
private static class SbufferComparator implements Comparator<StringBuffer> {

        @Override
        public int compare(StringBuffer s1, StringBuffer s2) {
            return s1.toString().compareTo(s2.toString());

        }

}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            StringBuffer one = new StringBuffer("one");
            StringBuffer  two = new StringBuffer("two");
            StringBuffer three = new StringBuffer("three");
            Set<StringBuffer> sb=new TreeSet<StringBuffer>();
             //The below line works
            //Set<StringBuffer> sb=new TreeSet<StringBuffer>(new SbufferComparator());
            sb.add(one);
            sb.add(two);
            sb.add(three);
            System.out.println("set before change: "+ sb);
            //This does not work
            Collections.sort(sb, new SbufferComparator());
            System.out.println("set After change: "+ sb);
        }
    }
```

PS. I know `StringBuffer` is a `bad` type to keep as element in Set. However, I was testing if Java allows to keep a mutable object in Set. (python does not allow mutable object to placed in set or dictionary(map))

Comment: Also note that StringBuffer is obsolete - you should use a StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Collections.sort()` can only be applied to a `List`, and you are passing a `Set` so it fails (it should not compile at all).

`TreeSet` is a sorted `Set`, so you should create it with an appropriate `Comparator` and the content of the set will always be sorted, without the need to manually sort it.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) expects a `List` rather than a `Set`. Try this instead

```
Set<StringBuffer> sb=new TreeSet<StringBuffer>(new SbufferComparator());
```

and remove the call to `sort` completely